# How can I determine who (or what) has blocked access to a centos user account?

Tags: linux, centos, user-accounts

CentOS 5.x

A user account on my CenTOS server has become inaccessible and I'm not sure why.

If I run `chage -l foo` I see:

```
Minimum:     0
Maximum:     0 
Warning:     5
Inactive     -1
Last Change:         July 17, 2012
Password Expires:     Never
Password Inactive:    Never
Account Expires:      Never
```

I'm not sure what the -1 means but as far as I can tell based on the other settings, the system shouldn't expired or automatically lock out.

Assuming that's the case, where else can I look to troubleshoot this?

Also, will the symptoms appear the same if the account is automatically locked vs administratively disabled vs just having a changed password?

---

Update: I checked /var/log/secure and I'm seeing:

```
Aug  9 07:11:14 foo sshd(pam_unix)[15122]: account foo has expired (failed to change password)
Aug 10 19:12:33 foo sshd(pam_unix)[900]: account foo has expired (failed to change password)
```

Interestingly enough, I'm also noticing entries like:

```
Aug 13 10:12:00 foo sshd(pam_unix)[23222]: password for user foo will expire in 0 days
```

Does this last entry mean that the password will never expire? Or that it will expire today?

Comment: `/var/log/secure` lend any clue?

Comment: What are the error messages you are seeing ? Does /var/log/secure have any relevant messages ?

Comment: Updated case description with /var/log/secure entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure what the -1 means

**`man chage`** says:

```
   -I, --inactive INACTIVE
       Set the number of days of inactivity after a password has expired before the account is locked. The
       INACTIVE option is the number of days of inactivity. A user whose account is locked must contact the
       system administrator before being able to use the system again.

       Passing the number -1 as the INACTIVE will remove an account's inactivity.
```

---

**UPDATE Mon Aug 13 23:02:37 ICT 2012**

```
account foo has expired (failed to change password)
```

It means that the `foo` account is expired and inactive. Reset his password.

> ```
> password for user foo will expire in 0 days
> ```
>
> Does this last entry mean that the password will never expire? Or that
>   it will expire today?

That's why you see the `Inactive -1` when running `chage -l foo`. The `foo` account will be inactive immediately after expiration.

If you set `--inactive` to different value than `-1`, the `foo` account has chance to do a "grace login" to change his password.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  For this specific account, I never want it to become inactive or expire.  How can I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: `chage -E -1 -I -1 foo`.