# PAM: auth: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure;

Tags: ldap, openldap, pam

We have opnldap setup on our ubuntu server, and were getting this message for a user:

```
 auth: pam_unix(dovecot:account): account has expired (account expired)
Sep  3 19:05:03  auth: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=XXXX rhost=::1  user=XXXX
```

I changed the password with ldappasswd successfully, but still the error persists.  Doing some research it seems that shadowLastChange is not getting updated.

How can we resolve this?

/usr/share/slapd/slapd.conf

```
access to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
        by dn="@ADMIN@" write
        by anonymous auth
        by self write
        by * none
access to dn.base="" by * read

# The admin dn has full write access, everyone else
# can read everything.
access to *
        by dn="@ADMIN@" write
        by * read
```

OK - this seems to be a PAM issue.

If I edit /etc/nsswitch.conf to :

```
shadow: compat
```

I don't get the message that the account is expired.

If I change it to:

```
shadow: files ldap
```

I do.  But in either case, I still get the dovecot error.

Comment: Does this help?

http://serverfault.com/questions/416338/how-can-i-determine-who-or-what-has-blocked-access-to-a-centos-user-account

Comment: no, because these are ldap users that are not in shadow...

Answer (score 3):

I *do* hate to revive a dead question but given that this is the top search result for "dovecot pam authentication failure ldap", let me add this bit of extra knowledge:

The only thing that I've seen in my testing that updates the `shadowAccount` attributes is the `passwd` command when you're modifying the password for a user in LDAP... Most other tools don't care much about the `shadowAccount` class and it's attributes, and won't touch them. However, I only find that `shadowAccount` classes need to be added to users *if they're going to be logging into the host*, since that **does** care. If you're just doing something like email authentication (Dovecot), then it's not much use. I *could* be wrong here, but I've yet to see anything other than a host login consult the `shadowAccount` attributes for anything.

Now, if you're having Dovecot authenticate *through* PAM (which, I assume you probably are, since Dovecot is querying it and you're changing `nsswitch`), then please bear in mind that while, yes, PAM will pay attention to those extra attributes, you still need the correct tooling to change them... meaning whatever is changing user passwords also needs to go through PAM. Unpopular opinion as it may be, if you're not requiring host logins, just services like Dovecot or others, there's no need to get PAM involved since it's going to be checking a lot more things that are likely going to be irrelevant. (At best it could enforce other things like, yes, password expirations, but personally I would not enforce things like that when the service you login to has *no provision to change a password* like that) It's likely easier in the long run to have non-host/shell login services check LDAP themselves, allowing for other things like search filters *specific to that service.*

However *assuming* you've set up Dovecot to check LDAP itself, and not rely on PAM, at the end of Dovecot's `10-auth.conf` are a list of `!include` lines for different auth mechanisms, like LDAP, SQL, etc. By default, the file `auth-system.conf.ext` is included *before* other mechanisms, like LDAP.
What this means is that, since, in my testing, Dovecot checks these *in the order they're provided*, Dovecot will first attempt to authenticate the user with PAM, and then, if that fails, authenticate with LDAP.
Ergo, you'll get a PAM error stating, yes, the `authentication failure` (as well as the first one indicating *what* failure it is). If you changed this ordering so the method most likely to succeed (LDAP, one would assume) is queried first, then there would be no need to check with PAM, and, therefore, no error thrown by PAM.

To solve this you *could* comment out the `!include auth-system.conf.ext`, but this could potentically cause system users (like `root` or `postmaster`) to be considered non-existent if you don't have them set up in LDAP.

My personal solution to this one was to cut that line out and paste it at the *bottom*, like this:

```
#!include auth-deny.conf.ext
#!include auth-master.conf.ext

!include auth-ldap.conf.ext

#!include auth-sql.conf.ext
#!include auth-passwdfile.conf.ext
#!include auth-checkpassword.conf.ext
#!include auth-vpopmail.conf.ext
#!include auth-static.conf.ext

!include auth-system.conf.ext
```

This means that Dovecot will *first* consult LDAP, **then** consult PAM if LDAP gave no results, as far as my testing has shown.

Answer (score 0):

Never really answered my own question before, but I wanted to share in case anyone else ever comes across this.  It had to do with saslauthd not installed, configured, and running.  Once I did that, error went away.